# What if a comment should be the (best) answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, accepted-answer

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322757/modx-revolution-friendly-url-settings) was answered while "chatting" in comments. (I know that's bad and I try to minimize it as good as it gets).

What if the user, which gave me the solution, knowing that I'll appreciate his answer (I asked him), doesn't write one?

**Shall I then, after a certain time maybe, give the answer myself to the problem?**

Apparently, the question is quite general, so in my opinion it should maybe have an answer.

What to do in such cases? It isn't the first time, I see that kind of thing.

Comment: Usually comments are meant to clarify before giving an answer, if I find some answer useful amongst the comments, I'd ask the author to leave it as an answer in order to accept it (if he wants, of course).

Comment: On this post, @nKn's comment is worth of answer. If you think it has unique set of points which already hasn't been covered in the answers, ask him to create an answer or do it yourself :)

Comment: This is a pattern common amongst all stackexchange sites; it even has its own [tag on meta.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answers-as-comments). You'll see plenty of duplicates there.

Comment: Has the suggestion been discussed to add another flag reason on the comments section: _"This is not a comment, but it should possibly be an answer."_ ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While the other answers here contain useful information in some cases, consider the motivation of the person who provided the answer via a comment. If the answer can be provided in a comment, perhaps the answerer considered the question to be too trivial to warrant a full-fledged answer.

The commenter may be gently indicating that, while s/he is willing to help you, perhaps the question isn't useful to future site visitors because the answer can be easily [Googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=MODX%20Revolution%20Friendly%20URL%20Settings) or found in the [product documentation](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/content-types).

As [noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252482/what-if-a-comment-should-be-the-best-answer/252731?noredirect=1#comment9463_252731) by l4mpi, the commenter may be helping to keep the site clean by ensuring that the question is eligible for [automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year).

Comment: This exactly. It has the added benefit that it keeps a question eligible for automatic deletion, given that it is currently eligible - should the question be closed, an upvoted answer would stop it from being automatically deleted.

Comment: @George Cummins Thank you for another point of view. I didn't saw it that way, and yes, after the helping comment I have found an answer in the docs. So perhaps my dear helper was right to just put a comment.

Comment: @pc-shooter Just chiming in here with a "me too" -- I will answer a question in the comments when I suspect it will wind up deleted. While I understand and appreciate the site's policies and our community's evolving expectations of quality, I also understand that you, the person asking, is a human being on the other end of this series of tubes and you just need help. If you want to become a great SO user, that's another matter entirely; at the moment, you just want an answer, and I know the answer. I like to help people, that's why I come here. So I vote to close, then answer in a comment.

Comment: This practice has greatly discouraged me for years - as a goodly amount of questions in the 'unanswered' queues *are* answered, just in comments. So the queue is large and reviewing it requires visiting each one and reading all the comments to ensure you aren't addressing something already addressed.  (Then adding an attributed answer is another kind of awkward).

Comment: In an attempt to find the answer, I have suggested "things to try" in comments. A few times, I had the satisfaction of the OP replying happily that my suggestion fixed his problem, and requesting me to post as answer (comments to my own questions on occasion had the same result). Unfortunately unless OP uses my name in comment, I am not notified of this request. The question may be a good contribution for SO, even if the answer is not as straightforward as to be placed right away as "answer".

Answer (score 14):

If a comment on an answer contributes useful answer or an additional point to the answer: Ask user to update it in answer itself or create a new answer.

If a comment to a question contributes useful answer (I mean totally worthy of being an answer), ask user to add a new answer.

In above scenarios, if you sense that user is not going to do it, do it yourself. Stackoverflow supports self-answering, there's nothing wrong in that.

Users **may not** read all the comments. Only the enthusiastic people do.. Also someone who visits Stackoverflow in search of a solution to his problems **may not be** a regular member. Stackoverflow facilitates read and get benefited feature to rest of the world.

For this reason and to keep the post clean and increase the readability we should maintain answers in answer section and clarifications and discussion in comment section.
And the conclusion of these comments should be updated in/as answers.

Answer (score 6):

Ask the user to change their comment to a question, wait a bit, and add it yourself if they don't promote it themselves.

Don't forget that there's a nice *community wiki* checkbox for answers "[for the community, by the community](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)", which clarifies that the motive is to post the answer where the community expects it instead of to claim rep for someone else's work. (People seem to be very sensitive about moves that could be interpreted as reputation grabs, even if they're well-intentioned.) You can also check back later and accept the original commenter's answer if they add it after your window.

I was curious how long one should wait before promoting another user's comment to an answer—perhaps that deserves a separate top-level question—but I would assume that 24-72 hours is a good time depending on the activity levels of both the question and the user.