# Duplicated comments in the form of answers

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, etiquette

Not exactly a dup of: [What if a comment should be the (best) answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252482/what-if-a-comment-should-be-the-best-answer) Mostly because this addresses a slightly different issue.

Taking the linked above situation, lets say that a comment is the best answer, and for good reasons, it is a comment (such as the answer was very trivial or a typo fix). So, just to solidify, we are accepting that the best answer was a comment, and should only be a comment.

Now, another user comes along and tries to convert the comment to rep by posting it as their own answer (slightly reworded). I feel like this is poor gamesmanship, especially because they are taking credit for someone else observation (albeit, most likely trivial).

When I see situations like this arise, what should I do? I personally hate people who do this, but is there anything I can do about it? (Please note I am not a moderator).

Is down voting the proper action? Or is there more I can do?

Comment: Why are we here? For rep? maybe a lot of us... As long as this gives future visitors the possbility to find the (hopefully correct) answer faster - this doesn't bother me at all...

Comment: @Daniel: Seems you are missing the context: The question should be closed as off-topic and removed as fast as possible, it is just about worthless.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, after a second look I see what you mean...

Comment: see also: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/)

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR;

*Who cares a flying ____.*  (Hopefully you can fill in blank).  You are worrying about something that should not be a problem.

---

> Now, another user comes along and tries to convert the comment to rep by posting it as their own answer (slightly reworded). I feel like this is poor gamesmanship, especially because they are taking credit for someone else observation (albeit, most likely trivial).

If you are thinking of Stack Overflow as a game, then please go away.

That is a joke, but the point is if you are thinking in terms of stealing rep and gamesmenship, then you are completely missing the point of Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is not a game to be won.  Rep and badges are not prizes to be coveted.  It exists to provide good answers to good questions, and be a source of high quality programming questions and answers, with some imaginary internet points thrown in to offer a little incentive.  It exists to help other people with programming problems they might be experiencing.  Treating it as a game and worry about someone trying to snipe rep does a disservice to everyone who participates for the right reasons.

Granted that many questions that come into the site (especially recently) are not **high** quality, answers (especially good answers) are still the key.  If someone leaves a comment, then they don't necessarily think it is the answer (or they don't want the rep from leaving it as answer).  If someone comes in and tries to convert the comment to an answer, they are actually doing good work because they are trying to provide an **answer** to an **unanswered** question (comments are not answers).

Unless you find someone doing thousands of rep points this way, I wouldn't worry about it.

Now if you do find a question that is this trivial and the solution is nothing more than a typo, it is possible that the question may actually need to be closed.  There is a close reason just for typo questions.  As you don't have 3K rep to vote to close, you can still flag to close by clicking "flag", selecting "should be closed for another reason", and picking the appropriate reason (note that there are several more reasons *hidden* under the "off-topic" option).  Flagging will send the question into the review queue for other users with close privileges to handle.

Comment: _Who cares a flying..._ Pig? :P

Comment: I think the "game" part of Stack Overflow is a large part of what makes it successful. Besides, rep might not be very important when you pass 2-3k but when trying to get established on the site rep is rather important.

Comment: @SamuelÅslund but the OP here is worried about someone "stealing" rep by taking comments and turning them into answers.  The point is the game is secondary to the site.  Sure the game has probably made SO successful, but it is still not what the site is about, so the point is don't worry about it.  If it is a good answer, upvote it.  If it isn't a good answer, downvote it.  If the question needs closed, then vote/flag to close it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "the best answer should be a comment".

According to the [site policy on comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), they should only be used to:

- Request clarification from the author;
- Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
- Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Today I saw a question that was fully answered by a comment; and then a moderator came along and deleted the comment.  (I got some bonus karma by retyping the comment as a two-line answer...)

It seems to me that the question should either be closed, or have an answer posted; even if the answer can be expressed succinctly.

Comment: I often post quasi-answers as comments to questions that I think should be summarily closed and deleted. If you want to scrounge [temporary] rep out of them, then be my guest. But I don't think it is generally appropriate to answer a question you're voting to close.

Comment: @CodyGray sometimes I vote to close a question but others don't, so the question stays open.. I guess answering and voting is like having a bob each way.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is downvote.

If the commenter wanted to post an answer, they would have, but they didn't, so answers are fair game. I also dislike when people do this, but it doesn't warrant deletion unless it is an *exact* or (**very** close) duplicate.

As long as it expands on the contents of the comment and adds something useful, it's fine.

In fact, if it does that, I would upvote it.

If it's an exact duplicate, flag it.

Otherwise, there's nothing you can do but downvote it, and, since you may vote as you please, no one can argue that you are unjustified in doing so.

There's a bigger issue here, though: questions that can be fully answered in a comment are usually questions that should be closed for one reason or another.

Comment: Though I would not upvote someone restating the typo someone else found, however much it was reworded.

Comment: @Deduplicator True, but a question of that type should be closed, anyway.