# Mark comments as answers

Tags: discussion, support, comments

Some comments are best suited answers. What should be done in such cases? it will be great if there is a way to mark them as answers.

Comment: See on [meta.SE]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answers-as-comments

Comment: @Unihedron: You don't like the singular? It worked before too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What if a comment should be the (best) answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252482/what-if-a-comment-should-be-the-best-answer) Or maybe better: [Answerers who only use comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments) Or even: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Comment: Dug out some duplicates and created the proper category for them. Does that kill your question? If so, mark it as duplicate to whichever one you think is best.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the person to post that comment as an answer.
There's not much else you can do.

I don't think a *"Mark as answer"* button is really necessary. In my experience, most questions that are answered in a comment get answered properly, soon enough.