# There is no checkmark for me to accept an answer

Tags: support

I'd like to accept an answer to my question (first time answer acceptor), followed these steps (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) but there is no checkmark next to any of the comments for me to click, just the `upvote` and `flag`.  What am I missing here?  :-)

The question in question...
[Bash - check command status AND store command output in local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658482)

[image: WheresTheCheck?]

Comment: Uber-Meta dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1555/175248

Comment: Those are comments, not answers.

Comment: Related: [What if a comment should be the (best) answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252482/7795130)

Comment: It is the cue to add your own answer.  Show everything you learned from the comments, don't just copy/paste them.  Complete the Q+A you started by marking your own post as the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no answer posted at your question you could accept at all.

Comments as you show, can't be accepted as answers, these are just comments.

Your question was closed as a duplicate, and no one would be able to post an answer as long it's in that state.