# What to do if somebody's comment is the correct answer

Tags: support, comments, accepted-answer

I have asked 2 questions on Stack Overflow where one of the comments is actually the correct answer. In both cases, there is another answer which, while helpful, didn't solve the problem. So my question is, should I accept the answer just to be nice, should I post a comment clarifying that the comment is correct (like I've done on one of them), answer my own question, just do nothing, or something else? Thanks for your advice in advance.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353204/what-to-do-about-undefined-behavior-error-in-c)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163187/how-to-change-django-static-files)

Comment: I mean... the comment on question 2 is hardly a useful answer, i wouldn't post that as an actual answer either. It's the equivalent of turn it off and on again

Comment: @KevinB True, but it was the one that solved my problem. So that's why I'm not sure if I should make that clear with my own comment.

Comment: tell the commentor that he should answer and you would accept it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What if a comment should be the (best) answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252482/what-if-a-comment-should-be-the-best-answer)

Comment: @KevinB Not sure what's wrong with that. It seems to be a perfectly acceptable Answer on Stack Overflow. See [this famous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936038/getting-project-nuget-configuration-is-invalid-error/40366369#40366369)

Comment: It’s evidence of no problem actually existing. Which... is exactly what happened in the question the comment is on.

Comment: If you do choose to post an Answer using the comment, you should probably link to the comment too, as per [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: @KevinB Isn't the point of Stack Overflow to increase people's knowledge of computer science? In my case I learned about static caching. It would have been really hard for me to get the answer otherwise since I didn't even know caching existed and the course I took never mentioned it.

Comment: I've deleted a bunch of inappropriate comments speculating about who might have downvoted a post. Discussion of votes is *never* appropriate in comments (as votes are anonymous), and [you should not make assumptions about who downvoted your post, because you're more likely than not to be wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686).